# Using née to indicate more than one previous surname for same person?

Tags: surnames

Can you use the term née twice when referring to someone married three times.  For example, "My mother Jill Smith, née Brown, née White ..."

Comment: See https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/12797/5183 which ends up discussing this though the original question is slightly different.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think the term née should ever be used twice in the manner you described in your question.

For someone born to a Brown family, who later married a Green, then a Smith, then a Jones, I would say something like:

> My mother Jill Jones, formerly Smith, before that Green, née Brown.

The term [née means born](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nee), and a person can only be born once.

Answer (score 3):

For registration purposes (in England/Wales) a maiden name does not mean the name a woman is born with, so the terms "née" and "maiden name" are not interchangeable.

In civil registration a maiden name is defined as "the name in which a woman first contracted a marriage". This will often be same as her name at birth, but not always.